# Why does rxjs-fetch close a Rx GroupObservable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

When I use a rxjs-fetch to add information to an GroupObservable, its gets exhausted. (further mapping operate on an empty Observable)

Let the code talk:

```
import Rx from "rxjs";
import rxFetch from 'rxjs-fetch'
import chai from "chai";

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('General', () => {
  it('combine group and rxfetch', (done)=>{
    Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
        .groupBy(v=>v%2)
        .do(modGroup => console.log(modGroup.key, modGroup.groupSubject.isStopped))
        .flatMap(modGroup => modGroup.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0))
        .do(console.log)
        .subscribe(()=>{},done,done);
  })
});
```

This outputs as expected:

```
1 false
0 false
9
12
```

Now adding some rxjs-fetch, that should do no harm at all:

```
import Rx from "rxjs";
import rxFetch from 'rxjs-fetch'
import chai from "chai";

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('General', () => {
  it('combine group and rxfetch', (done)=>{
    Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
        .groupBy(v=>v%2)
        .do(modGroup => console.log(modGroup.key, modGroup.groupSubject.isStopped))
        .flatMap(modGroup =>
          rxFetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts")
              .json().map(r => modGroup)
        )
        .do(modGroup => console.log(modGroup.key, modGroup.groupSubject.isStopped))
        .flatMap(modGroup => modGroup.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0))
        .do(console.log)
        .subscribe(()=>{},done,done);
  })
});
```

But surprise the output:

```
1 false
0 false
1 true
0 true
0
0
```

The two `true` indicate, that the GroupObservable is stopped and will not emit any further values. All I did was to fetch something via rxjs-fetch.

In my real world example, the key of the group becomes part of the request URL and the mapping a bit fancier, I reduced it to a hopefully minimal failing example.

Any idea, how I can achieve rxjs-fetch without loosing the groupObservable?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the reason of `0, 0` and closed Observables is following:

Assume, rxFetch takes **5sec** to get a value. While the source `.from([...])` takes **0sec**.
Now when you `map` rxFetch response to `groupMod` -- you map it **5sec** after `.from` has finished. So your initial group observables have completed and have no values on them.

Heres a kind of marble diagram:

.from:

```
1
2|
3
```

rxFetch

```
`----R|
```

result

```
`-----|

      ^ here we resubscribe to source groups
```

Heres a little example illustrating that https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/43d54c2c60acce4b580ed91d84f51789

Try both `.from` and `.timer` examples and also try increasing async task time.

*(it also has a suggested solution, see below)*

How to solve this. Well, its not very clear what your bigger intentions are, so I'll assume that you need the `rxFetch` response together with grouped values -- then you can use `mergeMap` to make a request for each value

```
.flatMap(g =>
  g
    .mergeMap(v => rxFetch('https://example.com/' + g.key), (a,b)=> a + b)
)
```

The key idea here is that we operate on groups that are combined with rxFetch and are waiting for the response; instead of directly returning completed groups.

Hope this helps